# Ant Design DatePicker component gives error when showing data in dynamic form with initial values

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd dynamic form for the update form. My dates in an array and I want to show them with < DatePicker /> and <Form.List /> .But I am getting

> moment.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: date.clone is not a function

> index.js:1 The above error occurred in the  component:

```
//object itself
const module = {
id:1,module_dates:[{date:"04/07/2021"},...]
}
```

And I convert all dates to similar with this "new Date(module.module_dates[0].date)" to be sure format as "Tue Jul 06 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)" but still getting the error. form component is below;

```
              <Form
                name='update_module'
                onFinish={SubmitForm}
                initialValues={{
                  module_dates: module.module_dates,
                }}
              >
                

                <Form.List name='module_dates'>
                  {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                    <>
                      {fields.map(({ key, name, fieldKey, ...restField }) => (
                        <Space
                          key={key}
                          align='baseline'
                        >

                          <Form.Item
                            {...restField}
                            name={[name, 'date']}
                            fieldKey={[fieldKey, 'date']}
                          >
                            <DatePicker />
                          </Form.Item>

                          <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
                        </Space>
                      ))}
                      <Form.Item>
                        <Button
                          type='dashed'
                          onClick={() => add()}
                          icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                        >
                          Add date
                        </Button>
                      </Form.Item>
                    </>
                  )}
                </Form.List>

                <Form.Item>
                  <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </Form>
```

If necessary I can create a sandbox as well. Thanks already.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AntD Documentation](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#DatePicker), DatePicker component accepts moment object as it's value, but string is given.

You should convert your date with `moment(module.module_dates[0].date)` or even better with `moment(module.module_dates[0].date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.